# Using multiple classes across android flavors

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

So I have an android base project that I want to split into various flavors. Assigning seperate xml's is easy enough, and so is classes. However the problem arises when there are calls from the base classes to the flavor classes. Say for instance I have:

```
package app.myapp.service

import app.flavor1.ClassB
import app.flavor2.ClassB
import app.flavor3.ClassB
import app.flavor4.ClassB

public class Class A
{
    Class B bar = new Class B;

    bar.foo();
}
```

So depending on the flavor build I still want to use the Class B implementation of it, however I cannot import both classes as each specific flavor won't recognise an import that is not in that project structure. Thus, on build of the project it will throw an error as that import is not recognised. If it were only two flavors I may be able to do a buildconfig to fix it however if the flavors become 2+ it becomes a problem. How would I fix this? Or maybe put differently can I still import multiple flavors from my base classes? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible, but one quick suggestion would be to create an interface for ClassB, then have said implementation in the flavors, and have some code in each flavor to set the implementation as the one to be used. The easiest way to do that is to use dependency injection, for example, have:

```
ClassA.setClassBImplementation(ClassBInterface obj);
```

And have an internal ClassBInterface variable that you can use in your code. You could then call said method from a class in each of your flavors to set the correct implementation.